# Windows Phone 8. Panorama control ergonomic ambiguity

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, panorama-control

I am developing Windows Phone 8 application.Everything is pretty good , but i found one thing i have not handled beforehand - and now than Panorama Control behavior confuses me.
Here`s simplified example of my application Hub Page (with Panorama Control):

[image: First panorama item with a lot of buttons]
[image: Second panorama item]

Simplified page XAML is next :

```
    <phone:Panorama>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <b:PanoramaBehaviour/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="Panorama1">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Button Height="72" Content="Button1" Click="Button_Click"/>
                    <Button Height="72" Content="Button2" Click="Button_Click"/>
                    <Button Height="72" Content="Button3" Click="Button_Click"/>
                    <Button Height="72" Content="Button4" Click="Button_Click"/>
                    <Button Height="72" Content="Button5" Click="Button_Click"/>
                    <Button Height="72" Content="Button6" Click="Button_Click"/>
                    <Button Height="72" Content="Button7" Click="Button_Click"/>
                    <Button Height="72" Content="Button8" Click="Button_Click"/>
                    <Button Height="72" Content="Button9" Click="Button_Click"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>

        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="Panorama2">
            <Grid Background="Red" Tap="GridTap"/>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>

    </phone:Panorama>
```

So the problem is next - often, when i try to swipe panorama from one item to another, i have one of buttons of first panorama item clicked. So i`m navigated to another application page.
Can somebody tell me, how do i prevent this panorama control behavior ?

-----------------EDIT:
EventToCommand solutions doesnt work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that one bugs me too and has been an issue since WP7. The solution is to use the `Tap` event in this case rather than the `Click` event as that doesn't give false activations in the same way. `Tap` is available on any `UIElement`, not just buttons.

Comment: Thx! I`ve tested your desigion. For now it is working, so it`s correct answer)

Answer (score 0):

DONE!)
As Paul Annetts told, tap event is raised in another way that Click event does.
So for Button on Panorama control solution is next :

```
   xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"

   <Button Content="Button1">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction IsEnabled="True" Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </Button>
```